# Is ''the''used with absolute adjectives?

Tags: adjectives

Is there some definite rule for it. In my book `the` is mentioned for some and not for others. For example,
***It's perfect copier ever invented***.
Shouldn't `the` be used here.

Comment: There is a different problem with that sentence: it doesn't make sense to use an absolute adjective with "ever". The "ever" implies comparison. What would sound correct is to either use "the best" ("It's the best copier ever invented") or to just say "It's a perfect copier" or "It's the perfect copier."

Comment: @sumelic Agreed. Or if you really want that sentence element you could change the sentence to: "It's *the most* perfect copier ever invented.". Or simply, "It's the most perfect copier ever.". [invented is implied]. Those are pretty bad form but they can work. A more idiomatic usage would be either what sumelic suggested or "It's the most perfect copier I've ever seen." or "It's the most perfect copier I've ever used.". Using "ever" requires that you distinguish its "gradability" as sumelic said. Another example: "It's the best copier ever invented.".

Comment: And let me clarify that the earlier versions I mentioned at the beginning of my comment would only be done in speech, never in writing (probably distinctly American I would imagine) but they are bad form and I would go with any of the latter ones or with @sumelic suggestions.

Comment: If you mean 'In my book' literally, you should give some examples from the book. In any case, some examples you have found are really needed. / Articles or other determiners are used with all singular nouns (not non-count nouns of singular form), no matter what adjectives come in between.

Answer (score 1):

I will give an answer since no one has bothered.

Either version you posted would be wrong:

1. *It's perfect copier ever invented.*
2. *It's the perfect copier ever invented.*

Both of these are grammatically incorrect. The first gives no determiner or qualifier for "perfect copier" and the second one does but the problem (and this is a problem with either one) is the use of "ever" in the sentence which implies gradability (even if perfect is an absolute adjective).

To correct it use something like:

1. It's the best copier I've seen.
2. It's the best copier in use.
3. It's the perfect copier.
4. It's the best copier ever invented.
5. It's the greatest copier ever made (or invented).

You need a superlative in particular because you are using "ever" in the sentence. Perfect is not the same as "best" or "greatest" in that sense. Those are superlatives and they make the sentence's word "copier" compatible with the use of "ever". Technically "It" is the subject and "copier" is a noun that modifies or renames the subject so it would be a subject complement. "Most perfect" is a superlative form. And that's why I mentioned it in my comments. It was a rather bad example, though. That's why I commented on it again. It's only used in speech typically and you won't find it in writing a whole lot.

Comment: @sumelic Thx sum. You are correct. I jumped the gun ;) I'll update the entry somewhat per your comments to make it clearer.

Comment: @sumelic Hahaha ;) Ok ok. I'll give you that one too. I guess technically because it doesn't receive the action directly or indirectly it really falls more into the category of subject complement (a noun acting on or renaming the subject). However to be fair to me (lol) I meant it more metaphorically not grammatically (just sayin) :)

Comment: Tip: the asterisk is accepted on this site to mark ungrammatical examples. Have a look at [the bottom of this help page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).